# Is there a dividend effect on stock prices?

Tags: stocks, dividends, stock-dividend

If a stock costs $100  and the quarterly dividend is $3, can I expect the stock to drop $3 in value when:

- the dividend is announced?
- the dividend is granted?
- the dividend is paid?

Comment: it drops on the ex-dividend date, which I _think_ is what you mean by "granted".

Answer (score 2):

Stock exchanges reduce share price by the exact amount of the dividend on the ex-dividend date.

You can read my explanation of this [here:](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/110554/how-do-u-s-stock-exchanges-specifically-account-for-dividends-and-ex-dividend-d/110576#110576)